# Tablefield output in No Results behaviour

Tags: views

I have achieved to display the raw value of this tablefield in views - Global no results but not in the table format.

I have this in PHP-format in the **Global - No results behaviour** in views.

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$node = node_load( $view->args[0] );
$table = $node->field_modal_parameters_tabel[und][0]['value'];
print $table;
```

This gives me this.

```
a:34:{s:8:"cell_0_0";s:1:"N";s:8:"cell_0_1";s:21:"nat. freq. meas. [Hz]";s:8:"cell_0_2";s:22:"&xij";s:8:"cell_0_3";s:1:"N";s:8:"cell_0_4";s:21:"nat. freq. calc. [Hz]";s:8:"cell_0_5";s:17:"damping calc. [%]";s:8:"cell_0_6";s:7:"MAC [-]";s:8:"cell_0_7"; ...
```

How can I display the table format?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer!!

```
<?php
$view = views_get_current_view();
$node = node_load( $view->args[0] );
$table_data = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_modal_parameters_tabel');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_modal_parameters_tabel', $table_data[0]);
print $output['#markup'];
?>
```